# chainerでTensorcoreを使って学習の高速化

Tags: chainer

Chainerでtensorcoreを使用して、学習を高速化したいです。
環境はCUDA9.0,cuDNN7.2,chainer4.2,cupy4.2 GPU:TITAN V
ネットワークはResNetです。(float16に設定済み）

この条件で学習を実行しますと下記のようなエラーが出ます。

```
UserWarning:The best algo of conv fwd might not be selected due to lack of workspace size
UserWarning:The best algo of conv bwd data might not not selected due to lack of workspace size
UserWarning:The best algo of conv bwd filter might not not selected due to lack of workspace size
```

このエラーが言うworkspace sizeとは何でしょうか？
tensorcoreは正しく使えてますでしょうか?

処理時間もtensorcoreをoffにした時のほうが若干はやいです。
バッチサイズを変えても結果は同じでした。

Answer (score 1):

CuDNNでConvolutionアルゴリズムを使用するときにテンポラリーでGPUメモリー＝workspace sizeを確保するのですが、ここのサイズが不足している可能性が高いですね。

解決策：次のコードをプログラムに追加する。

> ws_size = 256*1024*1024 
>   chainer.cuda.set_max_workspace_size(ws_size)

参考URL
https://github.com/chainer/chainer/issues/3922